# woocommerce attributes not showing on front end

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I have setup a Woocommerce store with hundreds of variable products (months ago). Everything has been working great with product variations/attributes so far, but today I got a message saying that customers are unable to pick a size for some of our products.

So, I have been looking into this, but I do not see why this is not working as intended...

I have set the attributes correctly on the back-end, I know this because it has been working as intended for the last 6+ months. I have also looked at the attributes & variations settings for these products, and they are all still set correctly.

Then, I double-checked to make sure the variation still had a price set, which it does.

Then, I checked the front-end of the site, and sure enough, the "size" attributes no longer show any options.

Any thoughts on why this might be? I have looked around stackoverflow a bit already... and the only thing I have found that I haven't tried yet, is: disabling all the plugins and reverting the site's theme to a default theme... I am *really* trying to avoid going down that road...

Sample URL (manually set product "Size" attributes on product page back-end):
https://www.worldequestrianbrands.com/product/contour-all-purpose-pad-with-bare-flaps/

Any/all help is greatly appreciated!

WordPress: 4.7.4 - WooCommerce: 3.0.5

---

**Update #1:**

**Follow up:**
After investigation, and an email from a fellow stackoverflow user, I have narrowed this down to a plugin version incompatibility with WooCommerce 3.0.5. Rolling back to WC 3.0.4 restored all the products' custom attributes to the front-end of the site. I am not sure what or why this issue happened, all I know is that rolling back WC was as a *temporary* workaround.

**More Info:**
When I first posted this issue on stackoverflow, I was running WC 3.0.5. When running that version, this was my experience:

- I have Variable Products setup with multiple Custom Attributes (set for each product, **not** through the WooCommerce > Attributes settings admin-sidebar feature of WC).
- If I went to edit a Variable Product with custom attributes, **all** of custom attributes showed up fine on the back-end, but only 1 of the custom attributes would not show any options on the front-end (e.g. "size" attribute).
- Looking again at the back-end of the product, the size attribute is listed, with variations, and a set price.
- I tried clicking "Update" on a product, just to see what would happen, and when the back-end page reloaded, the custom attribute I set was gone (e.g. "size").
- So, I figured it wasn't loading that Custom Attribute for some reason, so I went to the proper: WooCommerce > Attributes, and set the "size" attributes there
- Then went back to the variable products, and added the newly set "size" attributes, from the proper WooCommerce > Attributes that I setup
- Clicked "Update" to commit the changes, and there we go, now the "size" attribute shows up correctly on the front-end
- I manually updated over 100+ products this way
- A fellow stackoverflow user emailed me and mentioned he had the same issue, but rolling back to WC 3.0.4 worked for him, as a "workaround"
- I rolled WC back from 3.0.5 > 3.0.4, and boom, all the Custom Attributes we have set are now loading on the front-end of each product, as intended.

So, after all of that... I am still not sure exactly what is causing the issue, all I know is rolling back WC seems to allow certain Custom Attributes to be displayed again, on the front-end.

If I find out anything else, I'll be sure to update here!

Thank you again for any/all help with this! I am glad this 'workaround' is possible, for now, but the root of the issue is still unresolved.

I have not looked at any PHP or any other server logs yet, due to limited time, but I am happy to report any follow up info I can - or the actual issue AND solution! :)

Any other insights are greatly appreciated! I am still curious why this is happening...

Cheers!

---

**Update #2:**

This seems to be a known issue with WooCommerce 3.0.5, as stated on [github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14824)

"*We've identified the cause of the errors. This issue happens when you have a custom attribute with the same name as a global attribute. We're working on a fix now.*"

Comment: Here you can see screenshots of my back-end settings, and the resulting front-end: http://imgur.com/a/IjX7e

Comment: "disabling all the plugins and reverting the site's theme to a default theme." don't avoid it. That can give you very valuable information by isolating the problem. Also, double-check the back end that the size attributes are saved correctly.

Comment: Updated original post with more info :)

Comment: Nice update! I don't really know the reason myself, but if this is isolated (no plugin conflicts) to a version update from 3.0.4 to 3.0.5 it might be time to [report a bug](github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues) to WooCommerce.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks for the follow up also! I went over to github, and found another user having this same issue: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14844

Comment: I found this bug if I do not enter Value(s): for the "Size" attribute and click Save Draft.

But if I enter values, and then click Save Draft it saves it properly.

Comment: @FaisalAlvi that is not a bug - you are talking about trying to save an Attribute with empty values. Why would anyone do this? The **actual** cause of MY issue, is a known bug, as stated by a WooCommerce contributor on github: "This issue happens when you have a custom attribute with the same name as a global attribute. We're working on a fix now." See issue here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14824

Comment: Thanks for this post. I'm reading through it. It's possible I have the same problem.

Comment: FYI - this issue was fixed in the version of Woocommerce after 3.0.5 - that might help you @rpeg